# Добавление библиотеки в проект с описанием этой библиотеки

Tags: c#

Создал `dll` - комментировал в ней все классы, методы и т.д.
В исходнике `IntelliSense` все подсказки выдаёт из `<summary>` как положено, а вот когда я эту библиотеку добавляю в другой проект, все классы / методы без описания(

Добавлял `dll` через ссылки в проекте.

Пытаюсь гуглить - все пишут только как добавить `dll`

А вот куда девается описание ?

Его нужно как то отдельно собрать в `xml` и отдельно добавлять ?

Comment: проверьте, чтобы в настройках проекта было включено создание xml документации, и все, студия должна сама подтягивать эти файлы

Comment: @eXit спасибо - сейчас проверю

Comment: @eXit xml теперь создаётся - а как эту документация добавить в другой проект  ?

Comment: студия сама его будет использовать, просто в том проекте где, подключаете свою библиотеку, нажмите rebuild, или переподключите библиотеку и оно появится, и ещё если вы используете разные конфигурации (Debug/Release), то вкл. xml docs нужно для каждой отдельно

Comment: @eXit понял вас, спасибо!